# Select Distinct * as query method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, distinct, jpql

In my Spring project, I'm currently using only query methods.

Now, when calling `findAll(Pageable)` with a pageable that contains a sort of a collection property, I'm experiencing a known and expected issue:

[DATAJPA-744: duplicate results when sorting by collection property](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-744)

An easy way and also suggested way to solve this is by using the `DISTINCT` keyword to filter the result.

My problem is that when I create the repository method `findDistinct`, spring throws an exception on initializing telling me

> No property findDistinct found for type RoleEntity

My actual code:

```
@Repository
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<RoleEntity, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<RoleEntity>{
    Page<RoleEntity> findDistinct(Specification<RoleEntity> entitySpecification, Pageable pageable);
}
```

From the documentation I would have expected this to work: [SpringDocs: query-methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details)

So my question:

Is it possible to define a `Select DISTINCT *` with a query method at all?

Comment: can you show your actual code? it is most likely Spring is expecting a certain method with that name in your entity.

Comment: Sure. I've update the question.

Comment: On SQL level, `distinct *` makes no sense as that includes the primary key columns of the table and therefor the result contains no duplicates that could be removed by `distinct`

Comment: Depending on table joins, it can make sense I guess.

Comment: Then it would include the PKs of all joined tables - still no duplicates

Comment: the error means it expects a findDistinct method in your RoleEntity class, you've only shown an interface

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that is assuming there are keys used for that table. probably, but it is possible there aren't

Comment: Sorry @DN1 can you show the code of your RoleEntity class?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name When you do a `Select * from TableA` on a join result which is made on tableB you can have duplicate TableA entities. That's exactly the case here. Don't worry, my entities all got keys.

Comment: @HerrDerb: logically you would have "duplicates", yes. But technically not as `select *` includes all primary key columns of all joined tables - and _that_ combination of columns is always unique so `distinct` will never remove any duplicates. See here: http://rextester.com/SKXZE96368

Answer (score 1):

The List returned is already distinct as per the primary key. You must use `FindDistinctBy` some column name.